# Wordpress "Template missing", however all required files are there

Tags: wordpress, templates, themes

I'm using WordPress 4.2.2, my own custom theme and xililanguage plugin. The theme has worked properly until I enabled the xililanguage flags, which I believe could break the theme. Now I can't switch to my theme, because of that "template missing" error. Any ideas what should I do?

My folder structure:

```
|   comments.php
|   footer.php
|   functions.php
|   header.php
|   index.html
|   page.php
|   sidebar.php
|   single.php
|   style.css
|   style.less
|   wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php
+---css    
+---fonts 
\---js
```

Comment: What is the entire error message?

Comment: I can't enable the theme, because wordpress says that "Template is missing."

Comment: check your style.css do you have the comment for template recognition ? <?php /* Theme Name: your theme name */ ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I copy-pasted some not necessary template files from twentyfourteen theme, enabled my theme, then deleted these files and apparently it worked. I haven't got any problems with theme since then. Still I have no idea what caused this problem.